# Why is this code not replacing spaces with newlines?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut, tr

I have a file like this:

```
17336   GRMZM2G000118   GRMZM2G000118  
190207  GRMZM2G404941  GRMZM2G404922   GRMZM2G104854   
307596  GRMZM5G800488   GRMZM5G800488 GRMZM2G152059   GRMZM2G152059   GRMZM2G152028   GRMZM2G152028
```

line delimited by space
I was trying to cut fields from the second field till end, and convert it to be one column:
output should be

```
GRMZM2G000118
GRMZM2G000118
GRMZM2G404941
GRMZM2G404922   
GRMZM2G104854
...
```

using this command:

```
cut -f 2- < input.txt | tr " "  "\n" > new_file.txt
```

but it does not work

The only command work to solve it is:

```
 awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print $i}'
```

**Or**

```
 sed  's/\s\+/\n/g'
```

My question is why the first way do not work?

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact that you have multiple spaces. You may want to squeeze them beforehand: `tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d' ' -f2-`.

Comment: It was accepted as an answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have file like this:
>
> ```
> 17336   GRMZM2G000118   GRMZM2G000118  
> 190207  GRMZM2G404941  GRMZM2G404922   GRMZM2G104854   
> 307596  GRMZM5G800488   GRMZM5G800488 GRMZM2G152059   GRMZM2G152059   GRMZM2G152028   GRMZM2G152028
> ```
>
> line delimited by space I was trying to cut fields from the second
>   field till end, and convert it to be one column: output should be
>
> ```
> GRMZM2G000118
> GRMZM2G000118
> ...
> ```
>
> using this command:
>
> ```
> cut -f 2- < input.txt | tr " "  "\n" > new_file.txt
> ```
>
> **My question is why the first way do not work?**

You have two problems here:

- the default delimiter for `cut` is a TAB.
- multiple spaces are not squeezed together with `cut`, contrary to what `awk` does.

To address the first problem, set the delimiter with `-d ' '`. To address the second one, squeeze the spaces with `tr -s ' '`:

```
$ echo "hello     how are you" | cut -f2-
hello     how are you
$ echo "hello     how are you" | cut -d' ' -f2-
    how are you
$ echo "hello     how are you" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2-
how are you
```

All together your command should be:

```
tr -s ' ' < input.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | tr " "  "\n" > new_file.txt
```

So now you have a bunch of commands, time to move to the awk version : )

Answer (score 1):

Following command worked for me (assuming the delimiter is space).

`cut -d " " -f 2- <input.txt | tr " " "\n" >new_file.txt`

GRMZM2G000118
GRMZM2G000118
GRMZM2G404941
GRMZM2G404922
GRMZM2G104854
GRMZM5G800488
GRMZM5G800488
GRMZM2G152059
GRMZM2G152059
GRMZM2G152028
GRMZM2G152028

Can you add more information like what delimiter are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using this awk:

```
awk -v OFS="\n" '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/, ""); $1=$1} 1' file

GRMZM2G000118
GRMZM2G000118
GRMZM2G404941
GRMZM2G404922
GRMZM2G104854
GRMZM5G800488
GRMZM5G800488
GRMZM2G152059
GRMZM2G152059
GRMZM2G152028
GRMZM2G152028
```

`sub` function with `^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*` is for removing first column from each line.

Using `cut` can create problem for multiple spaces as it will convert them into multiple newlines.

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort compared to the simple loop that the OP used in the question!

Comment: hmm I think using a single `sub` is better than using loop

Comment: sed  's/\s\+/\n/g'  will do the work instead of this all effort and still the question is  why tr " " "\n"  not working with cut

Comment: I've replied why `cut + tr` is not working because of multiple spaces. Your `sed` command doesn't skip first column in each line and leaves multiple newlines.

Comment: Also that sed command is GNU-specific due to `\s` and `\n` so it won't work in all systems.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this : 
`cut -d' ' -f2- <input.txt  | tr " " "\n" > new_file.txt`

*Edit:*
**Explanation :** you need to add a delimiter for your fields.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` by default assumes that fields are delimited by a single tab character. It isn't possible to specify a variable number of spaces between each field, which appears to be what you have in your input data.

I would personally suggest using the awk script you have shown in your question, or something similar.